# Rendering the component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to authenticate the user. Initially when I receive the response from the server that the user has entered "the wrong password" I'm trying to set the state of authPassword. In render() I'm checking the state of authPassword and trying to display "Invalid message". But I'm unable to re-render it in order to display the message.

```
if(res === "wrongPassword")
{
     console.log(res);
     this.authPassword="password invalid";
     this.setState({authPassword});
}
```

```
render(){

        return <div className="base" >
                <div className="header">Login In</div>
                <div className="content">
                    <br/><br/>
                    <form className="form" method = 'post'>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" 
                                name="email"   
                                placeholder="email" 
                                className="form_field"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                            >
                            </input>
                            {this.state.emailError? (
                            <div>
                            {this.state.emailError}
                            </div>
                            ):null

                            }
                        </div><br/>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" 
                                name="password" 
                                placeholder="Password" 
                                className="form_field"
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                >
                            </input>
                            {this.state.passwordError? (
                            <div>
                            {this.state.passwordError}
                            </div>
                            ):null

                            }

                            {this.state.authPassword? (
                            <div>
                            {this.state.authPassword}
                            </div>
                            ):null

                            }         
                        </div><br/>
    {errors.form && <div className="alert alert-danger">{errors.form}</div>
                        }
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <div className = "btn">
                                <button type="button" 
                                    name="logbtn"
                                    disabled={isLoading}
                                    onClick = {this.handleSubmit}>
                                    Login
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be better if you share your code here, how would we know whats going wrong here? with that description above we can all post answers using our assumptions. so please whenever you ask anything, please share details and be specific about what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the issue.

```
if(res === "wrongPassword")
    {
         console.log(res);
         const password="password invalid";
         this.setState({authPassword: password});
    }
```